# RxJava - Adding new duplicate observer each call

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I have a function that gets called from the response of a Flowable. It's an API request that returns a Single.

```
    private fun syncUser() {
        getUserUseCase.getUser() //Flowable DB (Room) call
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnError { throwable -> throwable.printStackTrace() }
            .subscribe({
                users.postValue(it)

                loadUserOptions()

                isSyncing.postValue(false)
            }, {
                isSyncing.postValue(false)
                it.printStackTrace()
                log.e("Failed loading users")
            })
            .hold(this@MainViewModel) //extension function for CompositeDisposable.add() for interface CompositeDisposablesHolder
    }

fun Disposable.hold(holder: CompositeDisposablesHolder) = holder.hold(this)
```

The `getUserUseCase` object is injected in the constructor.
The problem is that any time this is called, I see an increasing number of calls to the API. The first time its called, there's 1 API request, the 2nd time there's 2, the 3rd time there's 3 etc...

I think what's happening is that any time I call `syncUser()`, it adds this observer to the observer list, so there are duplicates in the list. The result is, if there's 10 duplicates, the `subscribe` block gets triggered 10 times, which causes the `loadUserOptions()` function to be called 10 times.

Am I correct to think that each call to `syncUser()` is creating a new duplicate `Flowable`? And if so, is there a way to fix my code? Or is it something else entirely?

Thanks

Comment: Aren't Room provided `Flowable`s infinite so they keep posting update changes? You said the API is`Single` but afaik that can't have this issue. So either make sure the API is indeed `Single` or use `take(1)` to limit up to one signal per `syncUser` call.

Comment: I'm using the `Flowable` to update the UI so I need that and I can confirm it's as I described above. The API is definitely `Single`. I am having luck by not using `hold()`. Also, I tried to store the call in a `Disposable` and call `dispose()` in the `subscribe()` block, but I don't think that will trigger any future emissions from the `Flowable`.

Comment: @akarnokd Actually, `take(1)` works for the `Flowable`, as due to the design (previous dev), the function gets called manually on a button click. Tbh, I should just change it to a `Single`. Thanks